# Для каждого модуля свои настройки - как в модулях Joomla

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу сделать модули как в Joomla, но не знаю как.
У меня есть раздел **Каталог интеграций** в котором я вывожу все доступные модули и я хочу чтобы для каждой модули были свои настройки.

Например: 
Модуль вывода медиатеки из интсграмм. Я подключаю модуль и мне нужно вести clientID, token. 2 поля и кнопка сохранить.

Теперь второй модуль Интеграция с AmoCRM. Подключаю модуль, а там уже другие настройки.
Ссылка к СРМ, Апи ключ, Ответственные менеджеры  и т д.

Третий модуль интеграция с ВК. Вывод стены. Подключаю, а там поля cliendID, Ke ну и т д.

Модулей может быть много, но главное чтобы у каждой модули при открытии были свои настройки.

Как можно добиться такой цели?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте таблицу с настройками модулей и в админ панели интерфейс для неё (можно через отдельный модуль). Настройки модулей читайте из этой таблицы.

В общем случае как-то так...

Comment: Я понял что для каждой модули надо будет своя таблица, но я не понимаю как для каждой модули сделать отдельный интервейс.
Ссылка будет допустим такой site.ru/module?id=123 .... если так делать то для каждой я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы внутри менялся интерфейс

Comment: Вы можете создать такую архитектуру, где в каждом модуле будет лежать файл с настройками отображения, например json, в котором описываете поля для редактирования, затем при открытии страницы модуля вы читаете этот файл и соответственно его описанию выводите поля. Способов очень много.

Comment: Посмотри принцип структурных паттерном. Адаптер или декоратор. Тебе надо связать свою админку с модулями. Создаешь класс, который будет дергать объект другого класса, в зависимости от модуля. Вот в этих объектах и описывай структуру настроек. А свою таблицу для каждого модуля это бред. Храни все в одной или вообще в какой-нибудь mongo.

Comment: Вот примеры использования и описание декоратора https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/decorator/php/example

Comment: Не знание паттернов плохо для программиста)) Спасибо. Думаю я понял теперь что надо делать